# LiveScore automatic update on Prediction table

Tags: html, css

I created a Prediction table for my website but I want an automatic updated for my table from livescore. Please can anyone help me with the right code

This is the html table

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
>
> <html lang="en">
>   <body>
>     <table>
>       <tr>
>         <th colspan="2"><b>England » Premier</b></th>
>         <th><b>Prediction</b></th>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>         <td> &nbsp;24-06:20:16</td>
>         <td>Red Bull Bragantino <b style="color:red"> &nbsp;2 : 1 &nbsp;</b> Ponte Preta</td>
>         <td <td style="background-color:none;color:none;"><b>Home Win</b></td>
>       </tr>
>     </table>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

This is the css code

> ```
> table,
> th,
> td {
>   border: 0px solid black;
>   border-collapse: collapse;
> }
>
> table {
>   width: px;
> }
>
> th {
>   color: white;
>   background-color: black;
> }
>
> th,
> td {
>   font-size: 25pt;
>   font-family: Arial;
>   text-align: center;
> }
>
> td {
>   background-color
> ```

Comment: You mean update it from a live score service on the web? You will need JavaScript for this. And some kind of web-scraping backend probably(in your technology of choice).

Comment: you have just two ```th``` but three ```td``` and your third ```td``` has a typo: ```<td <td```...